# Allow an external user (through Cognito) to access a S3 bucket and console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to allow an external user (through Cognito) to access a S3 bucket and display the S3 console screen?

I have been trying to create a User Pool connect it with a role through Identity Pool and then in the APP SETTINGS in User Pool is my S3 url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to allow an external user (through cognito) to access a S3 bucket

Yes. Use Identity Pool => set Authenticated Role: S3 access with Cognito Identity ID restrict as example (custom prefix if you want): https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html

Then, User after authenticated with Identity Pool can access S3

> and display the S3 console screen ?

Not. User after authenticated has to access S3 via calling API

Comment: Hi mate, thank you for your answer. Then in this case, I need to build or get a thrid party interface to allow my user to connect with my buckets. So, I can't redirect my cognito users to my bucket and use the AWS Console Interface, can I?

Comment: Yes, only IAM User created can access AWS Console, Cognito User doesn't. You have to build the S3 clone UI base on Cognito User permission.

Comment: What do you attach this policy to ?

Answer (score 0):

You may create a new user in AWS IAM and grant the access only to s3 bucket.

- [AWS IAM User creation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html)
- [Grant Access to an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)

Then you would have the s3 web UI screen and AWS console authentication.

Comment: Hey @elbik, thanks. I was avoid mix the AWS IAM users with external users, but I will consider it as a temporary solution.